# SQL Permissions Conundrum

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2005
I have a user. We'll call him User1. He has access like so:

```
DB1 (read,write,execute)
DB2 (read,execute)
```

Here's what happens:

```
DB1..Table1 (can read, just fine)
DB1..Proc1 (reads Table1. works fine)
DB2..Table2 (can read, works)
DB2..Proc2 (reads Table2, works)
DB1..Proc3 (reads Table1 with a join on DB2..Table2...
```

Msg 916, Level 14, State 1. The server principal "sa" is not able to access the database "DB2" under the current security context.)

BUT!

That same SELECT ... JOIN works JUST FINE when not part of a stored procedure.

This is a serious head-scratcher, and it's holding up my work. Any ideas?

Comment: They're both on the same server, using the default DBO schema, which is also the default schema for the user.

Comment: The reference to "sa" is puzzling. Was DB1..Proc3 created WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'?

Comment: no, but I've just noticed something else strange. "sa" is linked to a user "dbo" on every database, except DB2 has blank for Login Name. Perhaps if that could be re-attached it would work?

Comment: That is probably the correct technical solution to this issue but I would not recommend associating user dbo in DB2 with the sa login without first discussing it with the DBA for the environment. Especially since user sa is typically in the sysadmin server role, which would make such an association unnecessary.

Comment: and nope, that wasn't it. DB2 gets replaced every three months, so the user list has to be rebuilt each time. I've got it automated, but I've no idea why the two databases aren't linking anymore. and it only happens in stored procedures.

Comment: I even set User1 as a sysadmin temporarily, and the message still comes up. Doesn't even tell me what the "current security context" is so that I can change it.

Comment: If this doesn't get fixed, there is a LOT of code that has to be moved out of stored procedures that were working fine a few days ago and into code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. DB1 needed to be marked as Trustworthy. The installer did it, but the updater apparently needed to do it again when it finished running.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, the fact that dbo isn't mapped to a login on the server is likely your problem.  Try `alter authorization on database::[yourdb] to [login]` (obviously replacing yourdb and login with appropriate values).